# "freeze" one column in flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, freeze, datagridcolumn

I'm using a datagrid to display a column of date ranges and several columns of data.  I'd like to make the first column (the date ranges) fixed; i.e. that column stays in place when the user scrolls the other columns.  That way, the dates column will always be visible as the user scrolls through many data columns.  I don't see a datagrid property for this; anyone have a solution?  TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

lockedColumnCount (and lockedRowCount) is more than likely what you are looking for.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html

The reason you probably didn't see it is because it is part of the DataGridBase and not part of the DataGrid class itself.

Comment: How do I use DataGridBase?  Flex help states " It is not used directly in applications."  Thanks again.

Comment: Woops ... answered my own question (it's visible to the DG, just not documented there).

Comment: yes, exactly.  DataGrid inherits all of those properties from the DataGridBase.

Comment: so would you say that this is the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

use locked column count property

lockedColumnCount=”1″ height=”96″ horizontalScrollPolicy=”on”

verticalScrollPolicy=”on” width=”397″>